# NextJs fetch data from api issues

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch

I have a simple NextJs typescript app with the app router.

I have the following code which works fine:

```
export default async function Page() {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js");
  const data = await res.json();

  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello from GetData</div>
      <div>
        <p>{data.id}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**But it stops working if I change the API URL to:**

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 or any other API e.g. https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I have also used types for the endpoints getting an array in response

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
const data: User[] = await res.json();
```

[image: Error screenshot]

**Console error**

[image]

**browser error**

Comment: How `"it stops working"`? what is the error you see? Include a reproduction if you can.

Comment: Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: fetch failed

Comment: I tried `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`. It's working as expected. Can you make a reproduction repo?

Comment: What do you mean by a reproduction repo? @AhmedAbdelbaset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example maybe a github repo

Comment: I have just created a new app and added the above code. It works fine for https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js and gives error if I change the URL to "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"

Comment: I did the same and it's working as expected. If it doesn't work in your case, create a repo with your code. I might take a look

Comment: Due to security settings from the company, I cannot push to a public repository. Could you please share your code, I can try that

Answer (score 0):

In React/Next, components are **not** designed to be ***asynchronous***. While you can technically make a functional component an asynchronous function, it won't work as expected. React expects components to return `JSX` synchronously. I am not sure how the given code works in the first scenario *(as far as I know, it shouldn't)*.

Here's how you can fetch data using a functional component and the `useEffect` hook:

```js
export default async function Page() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello from GetData</div>
      {data && (
        <div>
          <p>{data.id}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not work for server-side pages/components.